# How to get result of generated htmlstring from htmlhelper in controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, html-helper

I have a custom html helper in my App_code folder.
I want to call it from my action and get generated html string.
What should I do?
My MailTemplate.cshtml contents:

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@helper ContactUs(string body,string name,string email)
{

    <div style="direction:rtl;font-family:Tahoma;color:#3b7a09;">
   <span>از طرف:</span><span>@name</span>
   <br />
   <span>ایمیل:</span><span>@email</span>
   <br />
   <div style="background-color:#f5dfb2;font-size:13px;">
   @body
   </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: I want to generate email template in helper method And get it in action and send it to an email address.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, it has example of html helper method and that helper method use in view.

**HTML helper method in App_Code(App_Code\HelperMethods.cshtml)**

```
@helper renderheader(WebViewPage page, string displayText, string ActionName)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            @page.Html.ActionLink(displayText, ActionName, new { id = 0 }, new { @class = "btn btn-small 
                               btn-primary" })
       </div>
       <div class="span4">
          @page.ViewBag.ErrMsg
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

**Helper Method Call in View**

```
@HelperMethods.renderheader(this, "AddGroup" , "Create")
```

Comment: Thanks. But I Know How to call helper method in view.I want to get html of it in action.